# IOS :- Whenever I navigate to Another VC Searchbar Delegate Method Not Called And Not Show the Navigation Bar Cancel Button in Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, uisearchbar, uisearchcontroller, uisearchbardelegate

When I go to VC and click on NavigationBar SearchBar then Delegate Method is called And it show me cancel button to whenever I navigate to any other VC and come back to that VC and click on Searchbar it not called delegate method and does not show the cancel button Please Help me Thank You

My Code :-

```
-(void)setUPSeachBar{
     self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = NO;
     self.searchControllerInvoice.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = true;
     self.definesPresentationContext = YES;
     self.searchControllerInvoice = [[UISearchController alloc] initWithSearchResultsController:nil];
     self.searchControllerInvoice.searchResultsUpdater = self;
     self.searchControllerInvoice.delegate = self;
     [self.searchControllerInvoice setObscuresBackgroundDuringPresentation:NO];
     if (@available(iOS 11.0, *)) {
          self.navigationItem.searchController = self.searchControllerInvoice;
          self.navigationItem.searchController.searchBar.delegate = self;
          //          [self.navigationItem setHidesSearchBarWhenScrolling:NO];
          //          self.navigationController.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles=true;
     } else {
          self.getInvoiceTable.tableHeaderView = self.searchControllerInvoice.searchBar;
     }

     for(UITextField * textField in self.searchControllerInvoice.searchBar.subviews.firstObject.subviews){
          textField.subviews.firstObject.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor;
          textField.subviews.firstObject.layer.cornerRadius = 10.5;
          textField.subviews.firstObject.layer.masksToBounds=YES;
     }
     self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone;
     [[UIBarButtonItem appearanceWhenContainedIn:[UISearchBar class], nil] setTitleTextAttributes:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[UIColor whiteColor],UITextAttributeTextColor,[UIColor whiteColor],UITextAttributeTextShadowColor,[NSValue valueWithUIOffset:UIOffsetMake(0, -1)],UITextAttributeTextShadowOffset, nil] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
```

Before I click NavigationBar searchBar :- it called Searchbar delegate and shows cancel button
[image]

After NavigationBar I click on searchBar :-  it not called Searchbar delegate and not shows cancel button

[image]

SearchBar Delegate Method For Cancel Button Code :-

```
-(void)searchBarTextDidBeginEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar{
     [searchBar setShowsCancelButton:YES animated:YES];
}
-(void)searchBarTextDidEndEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar{
     [searchBar setShowsCancelButton:NO animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: from where this setUPSeachBar is called? ViewDidLoad, ViewWillAppear or what?

Comment: Hello, I have put this method in viewDidLoad but not work then i put this in viewWillAppear but still it’s not working now i have put this in viewwillAppear Method .

Comment: please put your total code blocks

Comment: In ViewDidload And ViewWillAppear i have written more code i don’t think thay that code is harm for this thing !! This is my main code for display NavigationBar And SearchBar !! Thank You

Comment: @AnkurLahiry Please check my update code Thank You

Comment: @YogeshPatel did you try this? self.searchControllerInvoice.searchBar.showsCancelButton = true;

Comment: It's working first but when I navigate to another vc then it not working !!